# How do you set the DateField in Vaadin 8 to highlight the default date according to the user's timezone

Tags: java, timezone, vaadin, vaadin8

I would like the `DateField` to be defaulted to my user's timezone. I've tried `DateField.setZoneId()` but this really didn't seem to do anything. I then tried to do `DateField.setDefaultValue(LocalDateAdjustedForTimeZone)` which mostly worked in that the blue box was correctly highlighted but the black outline remained under the server's timezone.[image]

Comment: See https://github.com/vaadin/framework/pull/10572

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see in the Vaadin client component `VAbstractCalendarPanel#buildCalendarBody()`, there's no way to influence which day is marked with the today CSS style `v-datefield-calendarpanel-day-today`. The client component Java code about determining "today" looks like:

```
final Date tmp = new Date();
final Date today = new Date(tmp.getYear(), tmp.getMonth(), tmp.getDate());
```

So I guess when it's translated to JavaScript it will take the current date on the browser's system.

However, as a workaround you can at least adapt the CSS styles to hide the today marker. I wonder why Vaadin did not think about your use case (which is mine, too). Can you open an issue at Vaadin please?